# ARM bootloader: the value of TEXT_BASE

Tags: arm, bootloader

It's important to calculate correctly the value of TEXT_BASE when we begin to program the bootloader, but I haven't found a tutorial well explaining how to find this value according to platform datasheet or other materials. For example, for arm920t and sumsang s3c24x0, u-boot defines TEXT_BASE=0x33F80000 with this reason:

> SMDK2410 has 1 bank of 64 MB DRAM
>   3000'0000 to 3400'0000
>   Linux-Kernel is expected to be at 3000'8000, entry 3000'8000 optionally with a ramdisk at 3080'0000
>   we load ourself to 33F8'0000
>   download area is 3300'0000

Can anyone explain the logic? Thanks!

ps: I also hope to know the memory layout of u-boot after load into the ram, the address of each data/instruction part, bss, rodata,zi, etc and the size. I expecte someone offer me some concerning tutorials to anaylyse, thank you!

Comment: possible duplicate of [ARM Bootloader: linker and program execution process](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21313448/arm-bootloader-linker-and-program-execution-process), why not just update that question with your new information.  At least delete the other one if you don't think it can be rescued.  Your **PS** doesn't fit with [the way *StackOverflow* works](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), maybe you should look for a mailing list or message board?

Comment: a mailing list? I really donot know how to find an appropriate mailing list and use it. In fact I use ARM Community too, I just donot where I could get an answer.

Comment: See [u-boot pipermail](http://lists.denx.de/mailman/listinfo/u-boot), [u-boot archives](http://lists.denx.de/pipermail/u-boot/), [google archives](https://www.google.ca/#q=site%3Alists.denx.de+TEXT_BASE+).  This isn't really **ARM** specific. [u-boot README](http://git.denx.de/cgi-bin/gitweb.cgi?p=u-boot.git;a=blob;f=README;hb=HEAD), [u-boot ARM memory map](http://git.denx.de/cgi-bin/gitweb.cgi?p=u-boot.git;a=blob;f=doc/README.ARM-memory-map;hb=HEAD), [doc directory](http://git.denx.de/cgi-bin/gitweb.cgi?p=u-boot.git;a=tree;f=doc;hb=HEAD).  Look at those, try something, then ask.

Comment: I used the mailing list of u-boot but the manager reject my question, perhaps the value of TEXT_BASE is associated with the board, so when we decide the board, we get the value directly with the file config.mk. We use it rather than calculate/modified it. Anyway, thanks for your information. It makes me figuring out a possible answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`TEXT_BASE` is, unsurprisingly, the base address of the U-boot image i.e. where it starts executing from. So if U-boot is running straight from flash, it's the address of the flash. Or if ROM/firmware is responsible for loading U-boot then it's whatever address in RAM U-boot gets loaded to. Thus if you set `TEXT_BASE` to a different address it'll be linked wrong and will probably break at the relocation step.

As for the image layout, what's to ask? Either read the linker scripts, or just run a build then disassemble the `u-boot` ELF image that `u-boot.bin` is created from.

Comment: This answer really doesn't give any guidance about how to find the text base for any particular board. Maybe you could give an example or two?